# Show that $x_1^2+x_2^2+(x_1-x_2)^3 \rightarrow \min$ has no solution

Tags: calculus, nonlinear-optimization

How can I show (preferably using the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem), that $x_1^2+x_2^2+(x_1-x_2)^3 \rightarrow \min$ has no solution? I can see that it is true, but how can I show it?

Comment: What does $\rightarrow \min$ mean?

Comment: Do you mean that the function is unbounded below on $\mathbb{R}?$

Comment: @EricAuld minimize the function.

Comment: @IgorRivin Yes, there are no restrictions on the domain over which we minimize.

Answer (score 1):

Change variables to $\xi := x_1-x_2$ and $\eta :=x_1+x_2$. Write the poly in these terms, and it will become clear it has no lower bound.

Comment: Thanks. I had a similar idea, but do such arguments really suffice as a proof though? I thought that maybe a more rigurous argument was required.

Comment: Well, you can't write "it becomes clear" in a proof, but can you prove rigorously that $\xi^3 + \frac12(\xi^2 + \eta^2)$ has no lower bound? It requires you to prove that as $|\xi|$ becomes large, $|\xi^3|$ will become much bigger than $|\xi^2|$.

Comment: Ehm, well I can again see that it is true, but no. How would you suggest doing that then?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the Bolzano-Weierstrass connection, but fixing $x_1 = 0$ (say) reduces the function to $x_2^2(1-x_2),$ which is obviously going to $-\infty$ as $x_2$ goes to $\infty.$

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought but I wasn't sure if it would suffice as a proof.